# ANR while working with EncryptedSharedPreferences

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-keystore

i am getting ANR in my applications broadcast receiver.

log from google console -

```
Broadcast of Intent { flg=0x14 cmp=in.medibuddy/.receivers.DailyInitHealthReceiver (has extras) }
```

Recently i have include EncryptedSharedPreferences by using this library androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0.
After that i have seen multiple ANR in google console related to app.
below log i am able to find in google console.

```
#00  pc 000000000005589c  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #00  pc 0000000000022363  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+38)
  #00  pc 000000000003d863  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+206)
  #00  pc 000000000003e339  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*)+240)
  #00  pc 000000000003729d  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::BpBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+36)
  #00  pc 00000000000cacd3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android_os_BinderProxy_transact(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int, _jobject*, _jobject*, int)+82)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native method)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:1145)
  at android.security.IKeystoreService$Stub$Proxy.exist (IKeystoreService.java:932)
  at android.security.KeyStore.contains (KeyStore.java:366)
  at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineContainsAlias (AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:1037)
  at java.security.KeyStore.containsAlias (KeyStore.java:1293)
  at androidx.security.crypto.MasterKeys.keyExists (MasterKeys.java:137)
  at androidx.security.crypto.MasterKeys.getOrCreate (MasterKeys.java:87)
  at in.medibuddy.util.UserStore.getSecuredPref (UserStore.java:34)
  at in.medibuddy.util.UserStore.getPref (UserStore.java:19)
  at in.medibuddy.MediBuddyApplication.initializeFirebaseAnalytics (MediBuddyApplication.java:211)
  at in.medibuddy.MediBuddyApplication.onCreate (MediBuddyApplication.java:201)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6304)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200 (ActivityThread.java:241)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1807)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7156)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

can anybody help me, why this is happening ?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: we are getting a rare ANR in `App.onCreate` with a similar stack trace.